# C++, Can't find loaded C# DLL while enumerating loaded modules

Tags: c++, dll, process, module

thank you for taking the time to read this.

The situation is basically, I'm using EnumProcessModulesEx to enumerate all the modules in a loaded process. I've verified that the process I'm getting with GetCurrentProcess is correct (via the ID). I seem to be getting all the loaded modules except the one I want! It's a C# DLL that is only loaded when the C# DLL function is called. I made sure the DLL was loaded before I ran the enumerating function. Is there a reason this C# DLL won't show up?

I also put this enumeration after I load a couple of other C# DLLs in my C++ code. It doesn't seem to be finding those either. All of these C# DLLs are dynamically loaded. I figure it shouldn't matter because a) everything is mapped into the process address space anyways, and b) I have a C++ DLL that is injected (dynamically loaded?) and I can find that just fine. My goal is to be able to hook a C# DLL function, so being able to find these C# DLLs is a must in this project.

Thank you all again for any tips or insights! =)

Answer (score 1):

`EnumProcessModulesEx` will not enumerate .Net DLLs.  It only enumerates native DLLs.

You can use the `GetAssemblies` method of the current `AppDomain` to enumerate .Net DLLs.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into that. I would upvote you but I can't. =(